# Restful Service Returning 406

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

I checked the headers and made sure I had Accept:application/json

I'm not sure why Spring is still reporting a 406, I can consume MVC controllers fine.

I looked and made sure I had all the right includes in Maven, so that shouldn't be the issue. I'm running Tomcat 8, and Java 8.

Any help would be appreciated!

RestUtilityController

```
package io.bray.springtest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.persistence.*;

@RestController
public class RestUtilityController {
    private static EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SpringTest").createEntityManager();

    @RequestMapping(value="/emailExists", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean loginConfirmation(@RequestParam("email") String email){

        List logins = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM LoginDto l WHERE l.email = :email").setParameter("email", email).getResultList();
        if(logins.size() > 0){
            return new Boolean(true);
        }

        return new Boolean(false);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring 2 MVC</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

                <!-- embedded jetty, good for testing -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/spring2</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

                <!-- configure Eclipse workspace -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>spring2</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd"
    xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="io.bray.springtest"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you share you client on how are you consuming this. Also can you try adding 'consumes' attribute with @RequestMapping.

Comment: I've tried accessing it directly through a GET request, from the browser, and using a jquery ajax call. All have given the 406 error. If I use consumes, won't that expect json on the incoming request? I tried it and it didn't help.

Comment: can you share the output of curl -v <url>. Please share both: request and response.

Comment: inside the controller, can you check the value of request.getContentType();